# What is this type of plug called?

Tags: connector

I would like to buy either a 17-way one of these plugs (see pictures) or a 12 way and a 4 way (the socket has a set of pins that aren't used so there's 4 double pins, then a gap, then 12 double pins).

Currently I'm using single female to male 2.54mm breadboard jumper wire. The female sockets fit on the pins perfectly.

This socket fits one of the plugs but I need a 17 way one (or 12 and 4 way) for another plug but I don't know what these are called in order to Google them and find one for sale.

Also, a secondary question, what do I need in order to wire this type of socket up? Is it possible to use the inners of the breadboard jumper cables (by pulling them out of the small plastic housing) or, if not, can I buy the 'pins' for this type of plug ready made or would I need to invest in some form of crimping tool?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: The black plastic bit is usually called something like a [rectangular housing](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319), and you would fit an 'insert' with a wire into whichever of the holes in the housing where you want to make a connection. Often you can get inserts with wires already crimped to them.

Comment: @brhans thanks for the info. Is this a specific type of rectangular housing? Looking online there seems to be a gazillion of them! (maybe not that many - but you get the idea) Also, do you know that the pre-made inserts are called? Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Everyone and their cousin makes those sort of things. [This filtered search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?k=&pkeyword=&pv88=35&pv89=1&pv90=2&pv563=3&FV=ffe0013f&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) shows 20 options for the one you're holding in your photo. If you click one and scroll to the bottom you'll get a list of 'associated products' which tells you which inserts go with that housing.

Comment: Take a look at Samtec. They usually have great documentation on this type of plug. I will say make sure the right pitch is selected for your application. ie 0.1" or 1mm can be overlooked sometimes. They are obviously not the same.